@sveltejs/enhanced-img causes build to seg fail
When using Svelte's enhance image package, building locally on my M2 Mac works fine but not on Cloudflare pages server. I have tried increasing max old space memory but makes no difference.
When I include the enhanced: true prop in the query of import.meta.glob, the build fails in Cloudflare pages.
Builds great locally.
Here's my import statement:
        ```const pictures = import.meta.glob<Image>(
            `/static/img/*.{avif,gif,heif,jpeg,jpg,png,tiff,webp}`,
            {
                import: 'default',
                query: {
                    enhanced: true,
                    format: 'webp;avif;',
                    w: '2400;2000;1600;1200;800;400'
                }
            }
        );```

Here's cloudflare's output:
00:21:22.278    > vite build
00:21:22.278
00:21:23.481    vite v5.2.9 building SSR bundle for production...
00:21:23.518    Images copied successfully.
00:21:23.792    transforming...
00:22:13.665    Segmentation fault
00:22:13.675    Failed: Error while executing user command. Exited with error code: 139
00:22:13.683    Failed: build command exited with code: 1
00:22:15.394    Failed: error occurred while running build command
Here are my deps:
Package.json deps:
    "@poppanator/sveltekit-svg": "4.1.3",
    "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "3.2.0",
    "@sveltejs/adapter-cloudflare": "4.4.0",
    "@sveltejs/enhanced-img": "^0.2.0",
    "@sveltejs/kit": "2.5.6",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "0.5.7",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "0.5.10",
    "@tsconfig/svelte": "^5.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^20.11.30",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.16",
    "base-64": "1.0.0",
    "eslint": "8.54.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-svelte": "2.35.0",
    "github-slugger": "2.0.0",
    "mdsvex": "0.11.0",
    "mdsvex-relative-images": "1.0.3",
    "node-fetch": "^3.3.2",
    "postcss": "8.4.31",
    "prettier": "3.1.0",
    "prettier-plugin-svelte": "3.1.0",
    "rehype-external-links": "3.0.0",
    "rss": "1.2.2",
    "svelte": "4.2.5",
    "svelte-check": "3.6.0",
    "svelte-preprocess": "5.1.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.5",
    "typescript": "5.2.2",
    "unist-util-visit": "5.0.0",
    "vite": "5.2.9"

